# How to fix An exception of type 'System.TypeLoadException'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, uwp-xaml

i am working on a Universal Windows Platform (UWP 10) C# application where i try to implement an AIML chatBot , but i find problems with this exception :

```
An exception of type 'System.TypeLoadException' occurred in AIMLbot.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Could not load type 'System.Xml.XmlDocument' from assembly 'System.Xml, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes'.
```

is there any thing  i can do, i was thinking about changing the Default.rd.xml !

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5321484/a-net-exception-typeloadexception-occured-in-the-module, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3094571/what-kind-of-problem-can-cause-a-typeloadexception, etc. If you want help debugging, you need to provide a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem. Without one, all anyone can do is offer general advice, and we have topics on Stack Overflow already that provide that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the exception message, AIMLbot.dll is unable to load System.Xml.

> An exception of type 'System.TypeLoadException' occurred in
>   AIMLbot.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Could not load type 'System.Xml.XmlDocument'
>   from assembly 'System.Xml, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes'.

You need to verify if your target framework for `AIMLbot.dll` can support `System.Xml Version 2.0.5.0`. You might have downgraded the target framework or if you are loading the assembly through

```
Assembly xmlAssembly = Assembly.Load("System.Xml, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e");
```

You need to check the version.

Comment: Have the same issue here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53649224/xamarin-forms-system-typeloadexception-clean-remove-bin-and-obj-folders-and
Can you please check